# PHP Curl Not formatting quotes properly; producing weird character set for single/double quotes

Tags: php, curl, quotes

I wrote a html scraper to scrape my various social identites, so I can make a real time 'biography' website.

However after using `curl_exec`, I find that texts that I have quoted, end up being formatted in a weird character set.

ex:  `"I love dogs"`  gets formatted to `â€™I love dogs â€™`
     `"I hate cheese"` gets formatted to `â€œI hate cheeseâ€�`

How do I either scrub these characters, or set curl not to format quotes like this.

Also, I have turned off magic_quotes.

Comment: Social networks hint you that they don't want to be scraped.

Answer (score 0):

had to change my meta header `<meta>` in my html document to a charset utf; It was ISO before.